# Cannot install spyder to run on Manjaro

Tags: python, spyder, manjaro

I am having problems to get spyder to install on Manjaro. Going through either `pip install spyder`, `pip install spyder=4.1.2`, or `pamac install spyder` I get the following error message when I call `spyder`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 204, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/spyder", line 8, in <module>
    start.main()
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 200, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 53, in <module>
    requirements.check_qt()
  File "/home/.../.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/spyder/requirements.py", line 41, in check_qt
    import qtpy
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 210, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

For some reason spyder seems to require `PySide`. That package however seems to be old (current being `PySide2`).

Thanks a lot, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) You said: "For some reason spyder seems to require PySide". That's not true. That message is only shown when no Python Qt bindings can't be found in your system. If you don't understand what that means, please remove all packages you installed with pacman and pip, and install Anaconda instead.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thank you very much,that is enlightening. I will give it a try.

Comment: Ok, the problem happens when you install spyder on a manjaro system as a user with `pip install spyder==4.1.2`. A simple `pip uninstall ...` does not fix the situation either. Still looking for a way to move back.

Comment: You have to uninstall several of the requirements of the spyder package that are added locally to run the original spyder again.